# How can I export/import autocorrect lists from Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Let's say I have several Google accounts, and I have a good autocorrect list in one of them, that I can view under `Tools > Preferences...`. If I want to transfer this autocorrection list to another account, is there any way I can export it from one account, and import it into another?

Answer (score 1):

Not a pretty solution, but syncing all the accounts with an Android device should allow them to share their dictionaries with each other.

Answer (score 0):

An indirect way to transfer autocorrects is to make a copy of the doc, then change it's content and name to what you want.
I think using a template will also do, but the autocorrects may not be linked.